# Merging these two count comparisons within if statement into one query to eliminate cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I know I should avoid using a cursor, but I'm struggling with this query. So I thought it would be best if I would have something working before optimizing. My goal is to update all children if none of the children have an email. That means that if any has an email, none of the children will be updated.

```
DECLARE @familyId INT
DECLARE @childId INT
DECLARE @famEmail NVARCHAR

DECLARE famEmailCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY FOR 
    SELECT ID, Email, ChildId 
    FROM #family

OPEN famEmailCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM famEmailCursor INTO @familyId, @famEmail, @childId

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    -- Check if none of the children have an email address
    IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #family f
        INNER JOIN Children a ON a.ID = f.ChildId
        WHERE f.ID = @familyId
        AND (RTRIM(LTRIM(a.Email)) = '' OR a.Email IS NULL))
    = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #family fa WHERE fa.ID = @familyId))
    BEGIN 
        -- Update email
        UPDATE Children
        SET Email = @famEmail
        WHERE ID = @childId
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM famEmailCursor INTO @familyId, @famEmail, @childId
END
```

This is of course very slow, so I tried to optimize it with `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` combinations, but every time I got stuck before I get a query that actually executes.

How can I get rid of the cursor, and possibly do this in one query?

Per request some example data.

```
-- #family example data
ID, Email, ChildId
133587,example1@example.com,133588
133587,example1@example.com,133589
133598,example2@example.com,133599
133598,example2@example.com,133600
133604,example3@example.com,133605
133604,example3@example.com,133606
133608,example4@example.com,133609
133608,example4@example.com,133610
133623,example5@example.com,133624
133623,example5@example.com,133625
133623,example5@example.com,134811


-- Children example data
ID, Email
133588,example1@example.com
133589,
133599,
133600,example2@example.com
133605,
133606,
133609,example4@example.com
133610,example4@example.com
133624,
133625,
134811,
```

Comment: Please share some test data for us to test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, one of the most valuable things when working on complicated queries is to break the task down mentally into subqueries.

So, first up: lets get a simple query that simply lists each kid and whether they have an email address:

```
select id as ChildID,
    case when (RTRIM(LTRIM(a.Email)) = '' OR a.Email IS NULL)
        then 1 else 0 end as HasEmail
```

... next, let's join that up against the family table, and get the count of the children and the count of email addresses, using that previous query as a subquery:

```
select f.ID as familyID, sum(HasEmail) as emails, count(hasEmail) as total
from
#family f
JOIN
(
    select id as ChildId,
        case when (RTRIM(LTRIM(a.Email)) = '' OR a.Email IS NULL)
            then 1 else 0 end as HasEmail
) as childEmailSubQ
ON f.ChildId = childEmailSubQ.ChildID
group by f.ID
```

Make sense so far?  Now we've got a query that has three fields:

- Family ID
- Number of children with email addresses
- Number of children in the family

Now we can use this as a subquery as well:

```
select familyID
from
(
    -- that text from the previous query)
) childrenEmailCountsSubquery
where emails = 0
```

That subquery gives us a list of all families that don't have a single email address amongst their children.  Personally, it's getting complicated enough that I'd just create a temp table to store the data:

```
declare @familiesWithNoChildrenHavingEmail table (FamilyID int)
insert into @familiesWithNoChildrenHavingEmail
-- the previous SQL command
```

... and then, you just make your update statement use that table.

Make sense?  Instead of trying to tackle it in one massive query, you're breaking things down into concrete steps (and you're even getting to document your process by descriptive Subquery/Table naming!)

Comment: I need some time to digest this. I'll be going to bed soon, I should have stopped working earlier... This does seem to answer my problem! I'll come back to you in the morning. BTW, congratz with 1k rep ;)

Comment: Thanks!  Yeah, subqueries are one of the most useful things in SQL.  It makes it possible to mentally digest more complicated queries, while simultaneously letting you document just what the heck you're doing  :-)

Comment: Midway I got the error `Column '#family.ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.` But I can work around that. Thanks for all the help. The aggregate subquery did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for something like this:

```
UPDATE a
set a.email=b.email 
from Children a
join #family b on a.id=b.id
where b.email is null
```

Adjust your logic as you see fit if this is not exactly what you want

Comment: I don't see how this does what it should do. How can I be sure that the Children do not get updated if any has an email?

Comment: I didnt fully understand your logic - thats why i said adjust as you see fit - my point was just that u can update off the join and u dont need a cursor here

Comment: for example, you could do something like update a set a.email= case when blah blah blah off of the join and put all your logic in the case statement